# <p> spacing problem in JS/CSS text flipper

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am trying to make an ambigram making tool that shows text in capitals and some other font both right side up and up side down. I managed to do this, but the spacing between the words is very big. Is there some way to get it to be near zero? I tried adding some margins to the css, but it seems to ignore it.

It is made as a wordpress plugin. You can see it running here: https://makeambigrams.com/demo/

```
<?php
add_shortcode( 'worder', 'worder_print_html' );
function worder_print_html( ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('worder-script');
    ob_start();
    ?>
    <div class="the_worder_contaienr">
        <form method="post" id="word-er-form" name="word-er-form">
            <input type="text" name="word_er_word" id="word_er_word" value="" /> <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Generate" />
        </form>
        <div id="the_result">
        </div>
    </div>
    <style>
        .the_worder_contaienr {
            text-align: center;
            margin:0
            margin-top: -20px;
        }
        .the_worder_contaienr input{
            margin:0
        }
        p.origgina_other_font, .upside_down_font p {
            font-family: serif;
            margin:0
            margin-top: -20px;
        }
        .upside_down_uppwe,.upside_down,.upside_down_font  {
            transform: scaleY(-1);
            margin:0
            margin-top: -20px;
        }
    </style>
    <?php
    //$output = ob_end_clean();
    return ob_get_clean();
    //return "foo = {$atts['foo']}";
}
function the_worder_jquery() {
    wp_register_script( 'worder-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . '/custom.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'the_worder_jquery' );
```

js

```
(function($) {

  $('#word-er-form').on('submit', function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    var the_input = $('#word_er_word').val().toLowerCase();
    var the_characters = the_input.split('');
    console.table(the_characters);
    var the_original = $('#word_er_word').val();
    var the_upper_case = the_input.toUpperCase();
    var the_revese_case = the_characters.reverse().toString().replace(/,/g, "");;
    console.log(the_original);
    console.log(the_upper_case);
    console.log(the_revese_case);
    var the_result = '<p class="original">'+the_input+'</p>';
    the_result += '<p class="original_capitalize">'+the_upper_case+'</p>';
      the_result += '<p class="origgina_other_font">'+the_input+'</p>';
      the_result += '<div class="upside_down_font"><p>'+the_revese_case+'</p></div>';
            the_result += '<div class="upside_down_uppwe"><p>'+the_revese_case.toUpperCase()+'</p></div>';
      the_result += '<div class="upside_down"><p>'+the_revese_case+'</p></div>';
      $('#the_result').html(the_result);
  })

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible,for this you must decrease all the styles of `<p>` tag as given below

```
p {
padding : 0px;
margin-top : 0px;
margin-bottom :0px;
height : 15px;

}
```

**Note :** Remember that the default height of the `<p>` tag is set to `28px` so you must decrease the height as well or else just by the other styles it might show some space.And if `style = "margin : ... "` is mentioned remove it.

Hope this might help you.